# Initializing Python class with array data

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

Suppose I have the code below:

```
class Person(object):
""" Capture user demographics data"""

def __init__(self, name, address, phone, gender, name_prefix):
    """ Initialize the object """
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.phone = phone
    self.gender = gender
    self.prefix = name_prefix


def display_userdata(self):
    """ Returns user data"""
    userdata = {'name':self.name, 'address': self.address, 
                'phone': self.phone, 'gender': self.gender, 'prefix': self.prefix
               }
    return userdata
```

I can initialize the data:

```
newperson = Person("Ben", '9999 Gotham City, las vegas', '702-000-0000', 'male', 'Waiter')
```

But I have a feeling that the `display_userdata()` function is redundant if I could re-write `__init` to store as `dict`.

```
newperson.display_userdata()
```

It returns the output:

```
{'address': '9999 Gotham City, las vegas',
 'gender': 'male',
 'name': 'Ben',
 'phone': '702-000-0000',
 'prefix': 'Waiter'}
```

My questions are:

Is there  a smarter way to write the `__init__` snippet so the input is stored directly as python dictionary? I don't want to call the constructor with dict key by using `setattr`.

Secondly, Suppose the user has 3 phones or more (variable), how do I store this in an array while calling the object constructor. Think `self.phone = ['702-000-000', '413-222-3333' ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create the dict directly in the init?

```
class Person(object):
""" Capture user demographics data"""

    def __init__(self, name, address, phone, gender, prefix):
        """ Initialize the object """
        self.userdata = {'name': name, 'address': address, 
                'phone': phone, 'gender': gender, 'prefix': prefix
               }
```

then

```
newperson = Person(name="Ben", address='9999 Gotham City, las vegas', phone='702-000-0000', gender ='male', prefix ='Waiter')
print newperson.userdata
```

returns

```
{'phone': '702-000-0000', 'gender': 'male', 'prefix': 'Waiter', 'name': 'Ben', 'address': '9999 Gotham City, las vegas'}
```

To your second question, if you pass a list instead of a string to the phone parameter that will show up as a list, will that work?

```
newperson = Person(name="Ben", address='9999 Gotham City, las vegas', phone=['702-000-0000', '111-827-3509'], gender ='male', prefix ='Waiter')
print newperson.userdata
```

returns

```
{'phone': ['702-000-0000', '111-827-3509'], 'gender': 'male', 'prefix': 'Waiter', 'name': 'Ben', 'address': '9999 Gotham City, las vegas'}
```

Comment: Ah! makes sense. I think I was overthinking the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have your data as `list`, you want to pass it as a parameter when creating instance of `Person` this why:

```
mydata = ["Ben", '9999 Gotham City, las vegas', '702-000-0000', 'male', 'Waiter']

class Person(object):
    """ Capture user demographics data"""
    def __init__(self, *data):
        self.userdata = {'name': data[0], 'address': data[1],
                'phone': data[2], 'gender': data[3], 'prefix': data[4]
               }
    def test(self):
            print self.userdata

>>>newPerson = Person(*mydata)
>>>newPerson.test()
{'phone': '702-000-0000', 'gender': 'male', 'prefix': 'Waiter', 'name': 'Ben', 'address': '9999 Gotham City, las vegas'}
```

But Here you have to keep your data organized in your `list` in standard way, 
Otherwise you better use `dictionary` instead of `list`, this way:

```
>>>mydata = {'name':"Ben", 'address':'9999 Gotham City, las vegas', 'phone':'702-000-0000', 'gender':'male', 'prefix':'Waiter'}

>>>class Person(object):
       """ Capture user demographics data"""

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            """ Initialize the object """
           self.userdata = kwargs
       def test(self):
            print self.userdata

>>>newPerson = Person(**mydata)
>>>newPerson.test()
{'phone': '702-000-0000', 'gender': 'male', 'prefix': 'Waiter', 'name': 'Ben', 'address': '9999 Gotham City, las vegas'}
```

Comment: Ah! lightbulb moment. I can actually iterate inside the `__init__` to dynamically create my keys! 

`def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    keys = sorted(kwargs.keys())
    self.userdata = {key:kwargs[key] for key in keys} `

Comment: Yes...You can do that...even better..:) .. but you cannot keep the order you want in the `dictionary` by using `keys = sorted(kwargs.keys())`

Comment: Yeah, I get your point. So I end up having `name` in the middle of my dictionary.

Comment: @Afloz .. There is not point in making such expression: `self.userdata = {key:kwargs[key] for key in kwargs.keys()}` .. it's the same as `self.userdata = kwargs` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by using keyword arguments in python (**kwargs).
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: That'd require me to do something like `newperson = Person(name="Ben", address='9999 Gotham City, las vegas', phone='702-000-0000', gender='male', prefix='Waiter')`

which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Afloz if your data is already organized as a list like you've shown, i.e. `data = ["Ben", '9999 Gotham City, las vegas', '702-000-0000', 'male', 'Waiter']` you can just wrap this with the `tuple` function and then call `newperson = Person(*tuple(data))` if you don't want to call each variable by assignment, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say you don't want to use the construction `newperson = Person(name="Ben", address='9999 Gotham City, las vegas', phone='702-000-0000', gender='male', prefix='Waiter')`

Comment: Thanks for comment on `**kwargs`. I never knew how to use it until now! @Khalil's suggestion with your gave a nice idea.